# Overlap between Many-Body States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, many-body

Let's say we have the two many-body states
$$ |\psi_k\rangle=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n c_k^\dagger\right)|0\rangle ,\qquad |\psi_\lambda\rangle=\left(\prod_{\lambda=1}^n c_\lambda^\dagger\right)|0\rangle \tag{1}$$
where $k$ and $\lambda$ label the states in different basis. These are related by
$$ c_k=\sum_\lambda \langle k| \lambda  \rangle c_\lambda ,\qquad c_k^\dagger=\sum_\lambda \langle  \lambda  |k\rangle c_\lambda^\dagger\tag{2}$$
Are there techniques to evaluate $\langle\psi_k|\psi_\lambda\rangle$? My first approach is to write

$$ |\psi_\lambda \rangle = \left(\prod_{\lambda'} \sum_k \langle \lambda'|k\rangle c_k^\dagger\right)|0\rangle\tag{3}$$
and then try to expand the sums and match operators in the same basis.
This, however, seems to be a nightmare! Is there a different approach?

Comment: Now expand out (3) and collect all the coefficients corresponding to the state $|\psi_\lambda\rangle$. The result is a Slater determinant.

Comment: It looks like following this approach I will get that the answer is the determinant of the matrix $\langle k | \lambda \rangle$. Is this correct?

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the overlap of many-body wavefunctions is in general a fairly difficult task. There are some clever algorithms that reduce the nightmarish-ness - you may find e.g. the one presented in [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.5b01148) to be of interest.